# Value is not getting clear in UI in React-Suite DatePicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker

I am setting value `onSelect` and clearing value on button click. The state for `DatePicker` field is getting cleared but from UI the value is not getting cleared. It remains there until and unless I clicked on cross icon in `DatePicker` field. I am also facing another issue which is whenever I put value attribute `value={moment(searchData.createdDate).toDate()}` and when I clicked on field it is throwing me `Invalid time error` error. Please refer the below code and image for more clarification.

```
import { DatePicker } from 'rsuite';
< DatePicker
oneTap
placeholder = "Date select"
name = "createdDate"
onSelect = {(date, event) => {
        handleInputChange({
            target: {
                name: "createdDate",
                value: moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
            }
        })
    }
}
    // value={moment(searchData.createdDate).toDate()}
    />
```

[image: The date value is still shown in field after clearing value from state]

[image: Invalid time value]

Thank you.

Comment: Include the properties in datepicker as `value={new Date()}` and `format={'YYYY-MM-DD'}` and for some reference go through this doc https://rsuitejs.com/components/date-picker/

Comment: @Lokkesh Thanks for your reply, but your suggestion does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue. The issue is with value which I am setting directly. I passed value within `new Date(searchData.createdDate)` and it worked as expected.

```
import { DatePicker } from 'rsuite';
< DatePicker
oneTap
placeholder = "Date select"
name = "createdDate"
value={searchData.createdDate ? new Date(searchData.createdDate) : null}   // correction
onSelect = {(date, event) => {
        handleInputChange({
            target: {
                name: "createdDate",
                value: moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
            }
        })
    }
}
/>
```